# setting scope of array_map php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, array-map

hey all, i use array_map from time to time to write recursive methods. for example

```
function stripSlashesRecursive( $value ){

    $value = is_array($value) ?
        array_map( 'stripSlashesRecursive', $value) :
    stripslashes( $value );
    return $value;
}
```

Question:

say i wanna put this function in a static class, how would i use array_map back to the scope of the static method in the class like Sanitize::stripSlashesRecursive();
Im sure this is simple but i just cant figgure it out, looked at php.net as well.