# Using a callback function of a different class in array_map --PHP

Tags: php, array-map

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setting scope of array_map php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329483/setting-scope-of-array-map-php)

I have a function called cube1() in a class called customExceptions.
In another PHP script I need to use array_map(), and for the callback function I want to use the cube1() function in the customExceptions class.
What is the syntax to do this? This seems a really basic question but I could't find a simple straight forward answer.

Comment: found the answer right here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/2329523 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class customExceptions{    
    static public function cube1($i){
        return $i*$i*$i;
    }
}

$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
print_r($arr);
$arr2 = array_map(array('customExceptions', 'cube1'), $arr);
print_r($arr2);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work?

```
customExceptions::cube1(array_map());
```